# When auditing a map of child entities as values with Hibernate Envers, the child audit data got deleted

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

We use Hibernate 5.6. We have two entities: A and B, B is OneToMany mapped to A as a value of a map; and four tables used for the child and auditing.

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class A {

    private String id; 
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "A_B", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "a_id"), inverseJoinColumns =       @JoinColumn(name = "b_id"))
  @MapKeyColumn(name = "propertyName", nullable = false)
  @AuditJoinTable(name = "A_B_ADT")
  private Map<String, B> bEntities = new HashMap<>();

}
```

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class B {

   private String id;  
   private String propertyName;

}
```

```
Table A_B (a_id, b_id, propertyName);
Table A_B_ADT (REV, REVTYPE, a_id, b_id, propertyName);
Table B (id, propertyName, propertyValue);
Table B_ADT (id, REV, REVTYPE, propertyName, propertyValue)
```

When we add a child, or update an existing child' propertyValue, every thing is fine, audit data is insert into the B_ADT table with new REV.

But when we try to delete an existing child, the child is deleted from B table and also deleted from B_ADT table. But the A_B_ADT table got insert a new record about the deletion.

We need to keep the deleted child audit data in B_ADT table.